# how to set an itemView for an itemController in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have successfully implemented an ArrayController an defined an ItemController for it like this:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(InboxTab, {
    itemController: 'messages.message-list-item'
});
```

then in the template for the array controller I just do

```
{{#each}}
<li {{action 'someActionFromItemController'}}>{{someComputedPropertyFromItemController}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

This works great and I can handle a lot of actions and computed for each item, but I'm running into difficulties associating a view to each item. The docs are not helpful. The only instance of itemView is in this article:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html#sts=Specifying itemViewClass

and here the example seems to revolve around adding the view to the template and specifying the content from there and I'm not sure how that applies to the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0):

A different way you could do it:

```
{{#each itemController='messages.message-list-item'}}
 {{#view your-view}}
   {{action}}{{computed property from view/controller}}
 {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

specify the item controller in the loop and wrap the actions and properties in the view - which means either of these could also be called or set in the view.

Comment: thanks, I just finally stumbled on that as well, is it not doable through the JS like an itemController can be set?

Comment: The problem is that through doing it through the template, intead of the JS. I'm not able to stay dry and have to repeat code.

Comment: You can still use the controller for the actions or the computed property, or you can pass in parameters in through the view when its inserted into the template. You also might look at components if your looking to stay dry. From the code above its hard to see why switching to a view would cause issues with having to rewrite code.

Answer (score 0):

I think way to do this best is with  `itemViewClass`, see the [api](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html#toc_specifying-code-itemviewclass-code) for the full details.

```handlebars
{{#each message itemController='messageListItem' itemViewClass='messageListItem'}} 
  {{! Assumes you have view defined in an App.MessageListItemView defined in your JavaScript}} 
  {{action}}
{{/each}}
```